# std::move used, move constructor called but object still valid

Tags: c++, move, rvalue-reference

Can someone explain why the original object that is passed to a new object via std::move is still valid afterwards?

```
#include <iostream>

class Class
{

public:
    explicit Class(const double& tt) : m_type(tt)
    {
        std::cout << "defaultish" << std::endl;
    };

    explicit Class(const Class& val) :
        m_type(val.m_type)
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    };

    explicit Class(Class&& val) :
        m_type(val.m_type)
    {
        m_type = val.m_type;
        std::cout << "move: " << m_type << std::endl;
    };

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "print: " << m_type << std::endl;
    }

    void set(const double& tt)
    {
        m_type = tt;
    }

private:

    double m_type;    
};

int main ()
{
    Class cc(3.2);

    Class c2(std::move(cc));

    c2.print();

    cc.set(4.0);
    cc.print();


    return 0;
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
defaultish
move: 3.2
print: 3.2
print: 4
```

I would expect the calls to cc.set() and cc.print() to fail...

**UPDATE**
Thanks to answers below, we've identified that 1) I wasn't moving anything in the move constructor, and 2) `std::move()` on an int or double doesn't do anything because it's more expensive to move these types than to simply copy. The new code below updates the class's private member variable to be of type std::string instead of a double, and properly calls std::move when setting this private member variable in the Class' move constructor, resulting in an output that shows how a std::move results in a *valid but unspecified state*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Class
{

public:
    explicit Class(const std::string& tt) : m_type(tt)
    {
        std::cout << "defaultish" << std::endl;
    };

    explicit Class(const Class& val) :
        m_type(val.m_type)
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    };

    explicit Class(Class&& val) : m_type(std::move(val.m_type))
    {
        std::cout << "move: " << m_type << std::endl;
    };

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "print: " << m_type << std::endl;
    }

    void set(const std::string val )
    {
        m_type = val;   
    }

private:

    std::string m_type;    
};

int main ()
{
    Class cc("3.2");

    Class c2(std::move(cc));
    c2.print( );

    cc.print();
    cc.set( "4.0" );
    cc.print();

    return 0;
}
```

And finally the output:

```
defaultish
move: 3.2
print: 3.2
print: 
print: 4.0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the standard says so.

Moved-from objects have a *valid but unspecified state*. That means you can still use them, but you can't be sure what state they'll be in. They could look just as they did before the move, depending on what is the most efficient way to "move" data out of them. For example, "moving" from an `int` makes no sense (you'd have to do *extra* work to reset the original value!) so a "move" from an `int` is actually only ever going to be a copy. The same is true of a `double`.

Although in this case it's got more to do with the fact that you didn't actually move anything.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you can invoke member functions on a moved-from object that have no preconditions (including assignment and destruction).

Comment: Can you explain the statement "you didn't actually move anything? Is this because I forgot to delete the initializer list?

Comment: @Wond3rBoi You used `m_type(val.m_type)` instead of `m_type(std::move(val.m_type))` in your move ctor. However, doing so doesn't actually do anything (for `double`), as explained in this answer.

Comment: okay makes sense...what if I changed the member var to a std::string instead of a double and updated the call to `m_type(std::move(val.m_type))`?

Comment: @Wond3rBoi: That would make more sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tried that and I still got the same output...that brings us back to the "valid but unspecified state"? So I can expect the calls to `cc.set()` and `cc.print()` to work as intended, but if I call `cc.print()` before the set call it would be in an unspecified state, and could potentially print anything?

Comment: @Wond3rBoi: Basically. It's hard to know what's practically happened in your case without actual details, but maybe you had a really small string stored in the SSO buffer (which, like an `int`, is not moveable).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's simply because I was printing after the set call...once I added the print call before the set we see the unspecified state, as I mention in the UPDATE to my question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wond3rBoi: Okay. Please put that information in an _answer_, not in the question. Only the question goes in the question.

Answer (score 3):

In the code example, `std::move` determines which constructor gets called. Nothing more. So `c2(std::move(cc))` calls the move constructor for `Class`. The move constructor for `Class` doesn't do anything to its argument, so `cc` is unchanged, and it can be used just as it could have before the call to the move constructor.

All the talk in comments and answers about the state of an object that has been moved from is about the requirements on **standard library** types, which will be left in a "valid but unspecified state" (17.6.5.15, [lib.types.movedfrom]). What you do with your types is not affected by that.

EDIT: sigh. You edited the code and changed the question. Now that your class holds a `std::string` instead of a `float` things are different, and the `std::string` object in `cc` is, indeed, in a "valid but unspecified state".